# Why are the data fields of ROS::Time signed values?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe a dumb question, but what is the motivation of having the data field of the ROS::Time structure be signed values? I suppose I can see some reason for having the "sec" field be signed in case there is a need to express a time before the epoch, but having the "nsec" field be a signed value seems to be an error to me.

How am I supposed to interpret a value where "nsec" field is negative? Does this mean that the values:

{sec: 5, nsec: 500_000_000} and {sec: 6, nsec: -500_000_000}

are equivalent values (please forgive the pseudo-Pythonic notation)?

It's just something that seemed weird to me as I went through the ROS message definitions and I was wondering if there was any motivation for this, or if it's just an "accident of history".

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314021/why-are-the-data-fields-of-ros::time-signed-values?/) by [BitBasher4095](https://answers.ros.org/users/39113/bitbasher4095/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros::Time` can represent time AND durations. It happens that durations can be negative, this explains why `nsec` needs to be signed as well.

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2019-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BitBasher4095](https://answers.ros.org/users/39113/bitbasher4095/) on 2019-01-28**:
Ah, okay. I guess I missed on my previous read-throughs that "Times and durations have identical representations." Seems like a bit of a waste and could cause confusion, but as long as it's documented...

Thanks!